# how to create link to open android app from browser?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, hyperlink, deep-linking

I want to create link for opening specific app which I got as apk package. this android app is still in development so, it's not available on play store. Also, note that I don't have source code or any other resources of application. I just have apk package.

I already try to find solution and I found deep linking but the problem is that I don't have `AndroidManifest.xml` file to do any kind of modification.
I also, try [automate app](https://llamalab.com/automate/) and the automation is working but there is no way I can use direct file as link.

please suggest me if someone has better idea other then changing current file.